# Cannot run Django unit test. Returns django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, mysql, django, unit-testing, django-models

I've been running unit tests (test.py) on my Django app for ages with no trouble. In my last session I was tinkering with my MYSQL database and models. I have been dropping and recreating the DB, deleting the migrations file and making migrations from scratch while I experiment with the models.

Now, the unittests won't run.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-2017.2.1/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 140, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/main.py", line 147, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 219, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/danny/PycharmProjects/AskArby/deals/tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from deals.models import Retailer
  File "/home/danny/PycharmProjects/AskArby/deals/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Retailer(models.Model):
  File "/home/danny/PycharmProjects/AskArby/deals/models.py", line 6, in Retailer
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  File "/home/danny/.virtualenvs/AskArby/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1061, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/danny/.virtualenvs/AskArby/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/home/danny/.virtualenvs/AskArby/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/danny/.virtualenvs/AskArby/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

PyCharm also tells me no tests were found.

This is the beginning of models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Retailer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    base_url = models.URLField(max_length=500)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    #css parameters for finding deals and subfields in HTML
    deal_container_css = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    title_css = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price_css = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    old_price_css = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    brand_css = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    image_css = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    description_css = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    #for things that look like deal containers but aren't
    exclude_css = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    shipping_css = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    product_model_css = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import unittest
from deals.models import Retailer

class RetailerTests(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['initial_data.json']

class TestRetailer(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.bestbuy = Retailer(Retailer.objects.get(pk=1))

    def test_name(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.bestbuy.name, 'Best Buy')
```

I'm using Pycharm, running runserver as a manage.py command. I have tried setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE from the command line, and it echos back the right answer: AskArby.settings. I try to call settings.configure() and it tells me settings are already configured.

Also, when I run runserver I get this warning:

```
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.
deals.Marketplace.listing: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
```

Why is my app seemingly failing to run my unit tests in test.py?

Comment: Can you explain the procedure how you run the test.py

Comment: I was using Pycharm's built-in 'run' function. When I use python manage.py test from the shell, the tests run fine. So it seems that Pycharm is the problem. Perhaps I will try creating a new Pycharm project and importing my files to it.

Answer (score 3):

if u run from ide and not from comandline,pls add thses code before your run method:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "[your appname].settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

good luck to u!

Answer (score 0):

Today I ran some test modules in PyCharm that have been run hundreds of times before and instead I got the Django ImproperlyConfigured error.

I found PyCharm wasn't correctly detecting that files were Django tests rather than regular Python files (it shows a different icon in the run tab for Django tests which includes the Django logo). I ran them a few times and eventually PyCharm got bored of annoying me (this took about 30 minutes or so) and detected them correctly. Don't ask me what was going on. I didn't restart the IDE. I just ran various test modules a few times and poked around. So -- this problem is not always user error, sometimes it is a bug in the IDE. Unfortunately that means I do not have a fix. Maybe JetBrains do?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and came here looking for an answer.  I think the problem is that you are actually basing your `TestRetailer` test case on Python `unittest.TestCase`, not `django.test.TestCase`.

Your code begins...

```
from django.test import TestCase
import unittest
from deals.models import Retailer
...

class TestRetailer(unittest.TestCase):
...
```

So your test class for TestRetailer is actually based on the standard Python TestCase.  That matters, as the Django TestCase includes some Django specific initiatialisation.